# Linking g++ minGW

Tags: c++, shell, g++, mingw

UPDATED 9:17 PM PST
SOLVED 9:51 PM PST

I am trying to link some libraries my g++ code in a minGW shell and I am getting the following error:

```
$ g++ -O myprob.o  -o myprob -Wl,-rpath $PATH/lib -L$PATH/lib -lprob7_cpp -lprob7
g++.exe: error: c:\mypath;c:\mypath\lib: Invalid argument
```

If I try and run this command without the `-Wl,-rpath $PATH/lib` part, which I think I should be able to do, then I get this error:

```
$ g++ -O myprob.o  -o myprob -L$PATH/lib -lprob7_cpp -lprob7
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lprob7_cpp
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lprob
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have been tinkering with this for hours and can't seem to figure this out.

I have already compiled my `.cpp` files successfully with the following command:

```
$ g++ -O -I$PATH/include -c myProb.cpp -o myProb.o
```

How can I correct these errors?

[UPDATE] I since reconfigured everything and -lprob_cpp is now in my library.  For some reason in wasn't there before.  Now I am getting the following error:

```
  undefined reference to `_gfortran_string_len_trim'
```

I do not know what this means...

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution.  The command `-o main -lgfortran` solved my problem when added to the end of the line in question.